# With Adobe Omniture how can you track campaigns that go through the Apple App Store (iOS SDK 3x)?

Tags: ios, adobe-analytics

How can you track campaigns that go through the Apple App Store (iOS SDK 3x)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the Answer from Adobe:

Hedi,

There is no out of the box support for campaign tracking with Apple in the 3.x sdk's. We are currently investigating this for a future release. Please follow our SDK forum for updates.

Hunter Peterson
Mobile Engineer
Adobe Marketing Cloud